# lua combination logic with priorities

Tags: lua

Im currently learning lua and want to make a system that can assign content, with different priorities, to displays.

There is a total of 6 contents and 6 displays. Content 1 has priority 1, Content 2 priority 2 etc.

The displays can be switched off and by that won’t show any content. So if 2 dislays are off, content 6 and 5 won’t be shown. Content 1 has to be the last content displayed when only 1 is available.

I thought about making this logic with tables but it failed at the beginning and now I don’t know how to continue…

Comment: `for i = 1, displayCount do show(contents[i]) end`? Please add your own attempts, maybe that makes the issue more clear for us.

Comment: Ok thx, sorry for asking, I wasn’t sure how to approach a logic like that and thought this platform would be the right place